# Insert into code

Tags: sql, insert

So I was trying to run this code it didn't work. 
Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with it?

```
INSERT INTO (LocationID,LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude)
VALUES (1,39.7392° N,104.9903° W),
(2,39.6172° N,104.9508° W),
(3,39.5807° N,104.8772° W),
(4,38.8339° N,104.8214° W),
(5,40.5853° N,105.0844° W)
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Is LocationID an Identity column? Your coordinates aren't in quotes. Etc.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. What is it supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: I started with this code and then I applied the other code CREATE TABLE Location
(
LocationID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
LocationLatitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
LocationLongitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
GO
SELECT * FROM Location
ALTER TABLE [Order] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Location FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LocationID(Number)
GO

Comment: Please include the error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `LocationID` is an `Indentity Column` that automatically increments and the other columns are `VARCHAR` :

EDIT: OP's comment indicated `LocationID` is not an `Identity`

```
INSERT INTO Location (LocatioNID, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude)
VALUES (1, '39.7392° N', '104.9903° W'),
(2, '39.6172° N', '104.9508° W'),
(3, '39.5807° N', '104.8772° W'),
(4, '38.8339° N', '104.8214° W'),
(5, '40.5853° N', '105.0844° W')
```

The problem with your current SQL is the missing table, invalid data types, too many columns/too few data values, too small `VARCHAR(10)` cols, etc.

Additionally, you may want to read about Spacial Data: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-sql-server-spatial-data/

Comment: I edited to account for your comment of LocationID not being Identity.

Comment: Also, your `VARCHAR` cols are too small for the text you're trying to `INSERT`

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 166
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Did you copy my most recent code? Your code is missing the table name, which would result in that error.

Comment: This is what I get from your Code Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 173
Invalid object name 'Location'.

Comment: Then you don't have a table named `Location` and I'll reiterate the fact your code is missing a table.

Comment: If you're in SQL Server, are you certain you have the right database selected?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I think I need to review the whole coding. thank you so much